# Android custom shape for zoom buttons

Tags: android, drawable, shapes

I'm a bit new with Android UI but I would like to know what is the best way to archive something like this? The only icon I have is 'plus' and 'minus'.

[image]

Is there a way with a custom drawable shape to build this 'half circle' shape? (So it would be two shape so that 'plus' and 'minus' are two different actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a shape like this:

```
<!--roundbox-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#999999" />
    <stroke android:color="#000000" />
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/round_button_size" />
</shape>
```

and in the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_size"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:background="@drawable/roundbox">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/plus_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/plus" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp" android:background="#000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/minus_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/minus" />

</LinearLayout>
```

also added this in the dimens.xml file:

```
<dimen name="round_button_size">50dp</dimen>
```

If you really want two separate shapes:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#999999" />
    <stroke android:color="#000000" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/round_button_size" android:topRightRadius="@dimen/round_button_size"/>
</shape>
```

and:

```
<Button
    android:src="@drawable/plus"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_size"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"/>
```

Comment: I see. In my case though plus and minus are two different action.

Comment: just add them in the linearlayout, ill edit the answer

Comment: check my answer again

Comment: I have replaced Button with ImageView because it was simply showing a grey box. But I got the general idea with the drawable. Thanks!